# Java: Regex to delete wiki markup of lists

Tags: java, regex, parsing, wiki-markup

I am reading a wikipedia XML file, in which i have to delete anything which is a list item. E.g. For the following string:

```
String text = ": definition list\n
** some list item\n
# another list item\n
[[Category:1918 births]]\n
[[Category:2005 deaths]]\n
[[Category:Scottish female singers]]\n
[[Category:Billy Cotton Band Show]]\n
[[Category:Deaths from Alzheimer's disease]]\n
[[Category:People from Glasgow]]";
```

Here, i want to delete the `*`,`#` and `:`, but not the one where it says category. Output should look like:

```
String outtext = "definition list\n
some list item\n
another list item\n
[[Category:1918 births]]\n
[[Category:2005 deaths]]\n
[[Category:Scottish female singers]]\n
[[Category:Billy Cotton Band Show]]\n
[[Category:Deaths from Alzheimer's disease]]\n
[[Category:People from Glasgow]]";
```

I am using the following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\*+|#+|;|:)(.+)$");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String outtext = matcher.group(0);
                outtext = outtext.replaceAll("(^\\*+|#+|;|:)\\s", "");
                return(outtext);
                }
```

This is not working. Can you please indicate how i should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)^[*:#]+\\s*", "");
```

Important is using `(?m)` for [**`MULTILINE`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) mode here that lets you use line start/end anchors for each line.

**OUTPUT:**

```
definition list
some list item
another list item
[[Category:1918 births]]
[[Category:2005 deaths]]
[[Category:Scottish female singers]]
[[Category:Billy Cotton Band Show]]
[[Category:Deaths from Alzheimer's disease]]
[[Category:People from Glasgow]]
```